# How do I read input to a script that is created by another script

Tags: input, perl-module

I need to make a change in each file.  The command I'll use is:
perl -pi -e 's/v8/v9/g'  #replace v8 with v9 for each file

I was given a tool that already creates a list of the files that need to be changed.  My script need to make the change then return to the original script which will re-run checksums and insert new checksums into database.

update_xml.pl -d 'dataType' -s 'myscript'

I can't seem to get the list of files created by 'update_xml.pl -d ' to become the input for myscript. 
Also how do I end the script to make sure the initial script (update_xml.pl) completes?

I am not a programmer so all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use redirects/pipes to handle flow control.  This won't do what you want it to do because there is no way for the child scripts to communicate their completion back to the parent, thus allowing the parent to proceed with the next step of the update process.  I would suggest that you modify update_xml.pl to do the following steps:

1. Find the necessary files.
2. Update them.
3. Calculate the file checksums.
4. Update the database as necessary.

So if I understand your question correctly, you should be injecting step 2 into the existing update_xml.pl script.  You could accomplish this with the following code, assuming the full path to each file is in an element in the '@files' array:

```
for my $file(@files) {
  my $cmd = "/path/to/perl -pi -e 's/v8/v9/g' $file";
  system($cmd);
}
```

If you want to use a separate script and specify it on the command line, use [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html):

```
use Getopt::Long;
my $modify_script;
GetOptions('-s=s' => \$modify_script);
...
if(-x $modify_script) {
  for my $file(@files) {
    my $cmd = "$modify_script $file";
    system($cmd)
  }
}
```